# I would like to make a 2d car animation like hill climb racing using the scroll wheel to go forward and backward. I'm using javascript, html, and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm just wondering how to use the mouse scroll listener. If you scroll down car accelerates forward and if you scroll up car decelerates and goes in reverse.

How can I write in JavaScript; while mouse wheel is scrolling down car builds velocity. while mouse wheel is scrolling up car loses velocity, Thank you!

Comment: Skip the idea of velocity for now, just work with a scalar quantity - speed.

Comment: a bit interesting for a project. Another thing to consider is the distance of scroll from base or scroll pressure (if they'll scroll just a little or scroll too wide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to `push` scroll values to array and calculate mean value (that may be your velocity) of elements, start with e.g. 10 '0'. After some time you may start to [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) last value or even [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) if there are too many items. I've added some example code below so u can get the idea. Of course that's really simplified approach.

```
const arr = new Array(10).fill(0);
document.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
  arr.unshift(e.deltaY);
});

setInterval(() => {
  let sum = arr.reduce((previous, current) => current += previous);
  let avg = sum / arr.length;
  console.log(avg);
  if(arr.length > 100) arr.splice(30);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: It turns out that the mouse wheel has acceleration built-in. So it works very well to just take the e.deltaY with out an average of 100 scroll points. in terms of runtime. I just wanted to let you know this information. I got it to work now thanks a lot.

Comment: Good to hear that. What do you mean by built-in acceleration? That e.deltaY can be different? I get only 100 and -100. I was thinking about improving that idea and adding '0' after some time of inactivity would give it also slowing down effect.

Comment: Scroll wheels do have a scroll acceleration/deceleration, but it's not accurate in terms of car acceleration. And yes I thought about adding a slow down if deltaY is 0 for a certain duration. The setInterval timer had bad runtime for me when I tried that.

Answer (score 2):

Listen for the `wheel` event and use the `deltaY` to determine which direction the user is scrolling and modify the velocity.

```js
let velocity = 0
document.querySelector('html').addEventListener('wheel', e => {
  velocity += e.deltaY * -1
  document.querySelector('span').innerText = velocity
})
```

```html
Velocity: <span></span>
<pre>(Scroll Here)</pre>
```